# Display big numbers in a small area

Tags: website-design, usability, info-visualisation, wrapping

I am developing an accounting app where I display several orders. Every order has a price. 
I have a box where I would like to display the price as shown below:

[image]

This works pretty well for fairly small numbers but as soon I start having big numbers the box is not suited anymore:

[image]

A solution I came up with is to only display thousands as shown below:

[image]

- Some of my users do not like the letter `K` that indicates thousands.
- Some of them want to the exact price and all the digits at once.

Making the box resize to fit all the price digits is not an option as this will make some of the boxes bigger than the others and the symmetry will be lost.

Are there any other ways of handling this kind of issue?

Comment: Do you have any limitations? It makes a lot difference if you have total freedom in how you can solve this.

Comment: Utilizing the K abbreviation is probably what I would go for, and then have a details view where the exact price is displayed. Disregarding that, why don't you justify the text from the center? If you let the text in the label be center aligned the 123336 figure in the image would fit. Of course that is a temporary solution since 7-8 figure prices would still pose a problem.

Comment: Why are you measuring price in Kelvin?

Comment: @dav_i Excellent user feedback!!! This is why I am hesitating to use the `K`

Comment: @GETah I was more making a quip on incorrect SI usage! My view on this is that you should use "k" - people are used to it in the context of 1km = 1000m etc.

Comment: Accounting apps should display exact amount.. i would prefer to increase size of the box..

Comment: If you need all the boxes to be the same width, that sounds like you're displaying data in a tabular format. If so, then use a `<table>`-based design: it's the right thing to do, and gives you benefits like automatically resizing columns to fit the contents in **every** row.

Comment: If you do use "k", please not that upper case is inappropriate for this. A lower case `k` is much more appropriate.

Comment: Who remembers the `MARQUEE` HTML tag?

Comment: There is definitely a tradition of using capital K for kilo, when the units are understood. Memory: 128K. Frequency: 3.8K denotes 3800 Hz.  Resistance: 2.2K resistor is 2200 ohms. GETah did not just pull this out of thin air. I'd keep this as K and tell the naysayers to go look at the faceplate of an equalizer. Mine goes from 20 to 800, and after that 1K, 1.25K, 1.6K, ... , 20K.

Comment: It is called "scientific notation". Floating points are based on that. You could start by implementing a default format and, then, add options for user to choose from.

Comment: @Kaz: that's usually done when the font is tiny, obviously quite common in electronics etc. – but otherwise, it does just look wrong. As for 128K memory: those are probably [kibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) rather than kilobytes, so you can't really compare it to the situation here.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Best solution will be to **increase the size of the box**. If you can do it without changing the layout, it is good.

For **reducing the font size**, I would suggest use a single size rather than going descending. It is easier to read.

And, if you want to do **'k' representations**, make sure the user has some way of accessing the actual number, via a tooltip or some other cue.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwU7p8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Tooltip won't work for a touch-based interface.

Comment: Unless the box has click/tap behavior you could show the tooltip on tap. Not sure if that would be discoverable but its a thought.

Comment: Well, for touch based interface, you could use a button that expands when clicked. Just be sure to sinalize to the user, if you don't use a button styled.

Comment: Putting the actual price in a tooltip also means that users can't select it for copying. I imagine copy/pasting a price would be a common task.

Comment: ah, number 3, copying stack exchange !

Answer (score 38):

Your layout should support your content. First content, then appropriate layout. You can not easily break the physical constraints (like small screen), but maybe even your biggest number could be placed as separate line at smallest screen.

Also I would recommend to keep in mind three stages concerning software:

1. Useful (Functionality)
2. Usable (Usability)
3. Aesthetics

The order is important, so don't let the Aesthetics beat Functionality and Usability.

Comment: third / fourth stage, understandable for the next developer - code usability !

Answer (score 33):

Something which is done here in stackexchange is **using colors** in combination with k's to display weight (and I'm guessing m's as well).

Look at how different colors represent different weight, in combination with the k's, you're receiving something which is unmistakably usable & understandable

[image: colors to display weight]

Reading further: Have you considered adding a tooltip/popover representing the exact number?

[image]

Comment: I didn't notice the "kviews" in this example. I think the layout works well, but the "k" should be part of the number value (which it is), not the label.

Comment: The "k" is where it is because it following the metric convention. You write "10 kg" not "10k g".

Comment: The color really helps it stand and maybe if it was not by it I would have missed the K connotation.

Comment: I understand the logic of "kviews" but I think most users would more intuitively understand "10k views" than "10 kviews"

Comment: @Stanley -- As a scientist, I'd just like to point out that both "10 kg" and "10k g" are correct in SI (metric) notation. One says "ten kilograms", the other "ten thousand grams." 10 kg = 10k g.

Comment: I never notice the `kviews`. I realize a question is "big" from the color difference and the relatively high number of votes and answers; that's what makes it stick out for me. The `kviews` only acts as a confirmation when I look more closely and consciously after I already realized it's a popular question.

Answer (score 11):

**Make the box big enough to contain any likely price.**

If your app has prices that might go up to six figures, make the price box big enough to take a six figure price. Do this even if you have to change the layout, even if real estate is limited and you have to sacrifice something else to make room for it. Don't use "K" or any other abbreviation to try to keep the price area small - as you correctly say, not everyone will understand it.

The reason I am saying this that for most people doing shopping price is a very important piece of information - more important than anything else except the basic "what is this" information. Moreover people really dislike being misled on price. If it doesn't look like you are being upfront about price, people will think you are trying to trick them - even if you aren't. The comparison with Stack Overflow reputation and the use of K isn't valid, as reputation isn't as important as price, and your audience is less likely to understand the abbreviation.

Answer (score 8):

Is the size of the box a limitation as was asked? The only reason I ask this is due to the fact that you can probably change the size of the box to the width of the largest price you have and set it as a fixed width for the box. Then center the price inside the box and you'll know that no other prices can exceed the width because you've buffered it using the highest possible price (you can perhaps add a few more digits to the maximum size you want displayed).

Also if you are going to use prices with a decimal number, I would just size the box once at the largest possible size and then you don't have to worry about the size of the box changing but you can start centering the prices inside them thus leaving you with a uniform look on the site.

Comment: Good solution but I'd suggest one minor change. Since it's an accounting app, consider right-justifying the numbers rather than centering them so the magnitude of the numbers becomes more apparent. This works best if you use a monospace typeface and with fixed precision numbers. If the precision varies within the list, line up the decimals instead.

Comment: That works and you're right. Generally most accounting applications don't have their data centered anyways. Plus, it's easier to read numbers that way as well.

Answer (score 6):

You could compromise on a mouse over for all digits (if that's an option), or you could make the trailing digits smaller / slimmer (if you have the resolution).

I tried with Calibri + Arial narrow, this doesn't buy you much:

[image]

(FWIW when using 'k' I'd use a small one, it distinguishes better from the digits and is SI-Correct. no such luck with 'M for million', though.)

---

Generally, consider reducing the total informaiton on screen. If you already have to squeeze in the data your problem is not the individual elements.

You could go for Currency symbol + value,

> $123.786

can be more compact than

> 123k
>    Price

---

[edit] as requested: The idea is to emphasize the most important information ("123" (k)) but still perserve the detail. I've seen the "one step" version (2nd and 3rd example) a few times, but usually for esthetics / style rather than for coping with information density. Using successively smaller digits was a spontaneous idea to extend this.

As the example shows, the "one step" doesn't buy much in terms of pixels, the second looks at least unusual, if not confusing.

Answer (score 2):

**Scientific notation would have you display this as: 1.23e5**, it's more 'correct' when it comes to units: 1.23e5 m is right, whereas 123k m isn't (it should be 123 km).

However if your users aren't comfortable with the 'k' postfix then I doubt they'd like this much, I merely mention it for completeness.

Other possibilities might be to have something like: **123<sup>thou</sup> or 123<sup>,000</sup>**

Comment: -1 scientific notation is not more correct in any sense when it comes to *displaying a price*.

Comment: @dan1111: I think a slightly unfair down vote: I specifically said 'it's more 'correct' when it comes to **units**'. I appreciate that the _content_ of the question means this may not be applicable, but for the _title_ of the question then I think this is useful information; it's possible that someone will visit this question with a similar issue in the future, and for which this information may be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing more, but here are some possible options:

1. Make all boxes resize so they are all as large as the one containing the biggest number
2. Reduce the padding to the left/right of larger numbers so they fit in the box
3. Make the number text smaller
4. Keep the 123K, and have the option of showing the full amount by some sort of toggle (click or hover or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

**Take a cue from the social media widgets out there.** Like/Follower/+1 etc buttons all need to show large numbers in a tiny little space.

Comment: Perhaps you would be able to include some examples in your answer, and explain why the way they do it is beneficial.

Comment: Well what *is* that cue? How do the widgets do this, and why is it suitable for this situation? You've not really answered the question here, more you've said -"Social Media widgets do something, go and see how they work".  Also, would that be appropriate for displaying prices? A count of how many people like a page isn't the same as displaying a monetary cost of a product.

Comment: @JonW There isn't a person on here, yourself included, who hasn't seen a facebook or G+ like button and doesn't know exactly what they do to large numbers. If you've read *any* large web news/magazine website, you know exactly what I'm talking about.

I respect the OP enough to not have to spell that out further for him.

Answer (score -2):

**Auto re-size the numbers as the price grows**; set one default size for the normal/expected price (2-3 digits let's say) and re-size it as needed.

Comment: It's a confusing, big numbers are small, small ones are big. This is clear example of cognitive dissonance.